# SAS to SQL Weighted Averages

Tags: sql, sas

I'm in the process of re-engineering some SAS code. I came across this snippet, and I was very sure my interpretation is correct (hopefully). However the final values don't tally. So am posting here hoping that someone can point out what i am doing wrong?

SAS:

```
     proc summary data =&indsn(&wherecl) nway noprint;
     var &varlist;
     class &byclause;
     weight sales;
     output out=temp mean=;
     run;
```

SQL interpretation:

```
     For each field in &varlist do:
      sum(field*sales)/sum(sales)
```

Is this wrong?

Comment: You are missing the `&byclause`; this would be a `group by` in SQL.

Comment: I suspect the WHERE clause may be the issue and/or possibly how missing values are being handled. How far off are the numbers? You'll have to show the full query, ideally with Sample data that replicates your issue.